# Using AMDClean with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, amd

So far I've been using [Almond](https://github.com/jrburke/almond) to do AMD module loading in production in my application but I'd like to go the step further and use [AMDClean](https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean/).

The application uses among other libraries, AngularJS. The Grunt build setup works perfectly with Almond, but when I switch the Grunt config to use AMDClean, the app does not load and the console shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
```

Which refers to the following line:

```
return angular.module('lingua-web', ['ui.router']);
```

In context:

```
app = function (angular) {
    return angular.module('lingua-web', ['ui.router']);
}(_angular_);
```

Looking at the rest of the build output I can see the `_angular_` variable declared right at the top of the file, but unlike `jquery` & `underscore` which are also declared there, `_angular_` is never assigned to.

**Extract from my Grunt config**

```
requirejs: {
    compile: {
        options: {
            baseUrl: "javascript",
            mainConfigFile: "javascript/config/requireConfig.js",
            include: ["miniApps/notebook"],
            insertRequire: ["miniApps/notebook"],
            out: "build/app.min.js",
            optimize: "none",
            skipModuleInsertion: true,
            onModuleBundleComplete: function (data) {

                var fs = require("fs");
                var amdclean = require("amdclean");
                var outputFile = data.path;

                fs.writeFileSync(outputFile, amdclean.clean({
                    filePath: outputFile
                }));
            }
        }
    }
```

**My RequireJS config (requireConfig.js)**

```
var require = {
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: "angular"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        jquery: {
            exports: "$"
        },
        "angular-ui-router": {
            exports: "uiRouter",
            deps: [
                "angular"
            ]
        },
        "jquery-ui": {
            deps: [
                "jquery"
            ]
        }
    },
    baseUrl: "/LinguaWeb/javascript",
    packages: [

    ],
    paths: {
        angular: "../dependencies/angular/angular",
        "angular-ui-router": "../dependencies/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router",
        "iframe-resizer": "../dependencies/iframe-resizer/js/iframeResizer.min",
        jquery: "../dependencies/jquery/dist/jquery",
        "jquery-ui": "../dependencies/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui",
        requirejs: "../dependencies/requirejs/require",
        underscore: "../dependencies/underscore/underscore"
    }
};
```

Does anybody have experience using AngularJS with RequireJS & AMDClean? Thanks.

Comment: Could you create a Github issue?  https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean

Comment: Issues submitted, thanks. https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean/issues/54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set `skipModuleInsertion: false` in the RequireJS config, or remove the config option altogether as false is the default value.

https://github.com/gfranko/amdclean/issues/54#issuecomment-52392856